# NPM: Installing Semantic-UI, the `semantic` folder does not appear

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, semantic-ui

I'm following these instructions for Linux:

https://semantic-ui.com/introduction/getting-started.html

to install Semantic-UI.  It seems that installing NodeJS went fine.  When installing gulp I get the following warnings but no errors.

```
npm WARN deprecated gulp-util@3.0.8: gulp-util is deprecated - replace it, following the guidelines at https://medium.com/gulpjs/gulp-util-ca3b1f9f9ac5
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@3.0.11: please upgrade to graceful-fs 4 for compatibility with current and future versions of Node.js
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: please upgrade to graceful-fs 4 for compatibility with current and future versions of Node.js
```

I tried following the instructions in the first line but it looked like all it does is just have you log issues or pull requests.  I'm not super familiar with how that works but my understanding is that this is just to alert the Semantic-UI team to issues, and so this isn't really causing my error.  I am not sure how to update or upgrade things except just to enter `npm update` and `npm upgrade` and I did that, although it didn't report that anything was updated or upgraded, so I'm not sure if it worked.

Initially when running the Semantic install it reported that it couldn't find a JSON file, so after searching that error I ran `npm init` and that seemed to fix it.  However, when I run `sudo npm install semantic-ui --save` it produces

```
npm WARN deprecated gulp-util@3.0.8: gulp-util is deprecated - replace it, following the guidelines at https://medium.com/gulpjs/gulp-util-ca3b1f9f9ac5
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@3.0.11: please upgrade to graceful-fs 4 for compatibility with current and future versions of Node.js
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: please upgrade to graceful-fs 4 for compatibility with current and future versions of Node.js
npm WARN deprecated browserslist@2.11.3: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.
npm WARN deprecated gulp-util@2.2.20: gulp-util is deprecated - replace it, following the guidelines at https://medium.com/gulpjs/gulp-util-ca3b1f9f9ac5
npm WARN deprecated hoek@2.16.3: The major version is no longer supported. Please update to 4.x or newer

> semantic-ui@2.3.3 install /home/abcd/Web/ExplainSemantic/node_modules/semantic-ui
> gulp install

[14:52:34] Using gulpfile ~/Web/ExplainSemantic/node_modules/semantic-ui/gulpfile.js
[14:52:34] Starting 'install'...

Current version of Semantic UI already installed
npm WARN explainsemantic@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

+ semantic-ui@2.3.3
updated 1 package in 4.06s
```

And when I `ls` I get

```
node_modules  package.json  package-lock.json
```

but no `semantic/` folder, which is necessary for the remaining installation steps.  So at this point I'm not sure what to do--fixing the dependencies doesn't seem to have worked and I'm not sure what else to do about that.

Answer (score 0):

I found what was wrong, somehow the `semantic/` folder got sent to my user folder (just above the Desktop).  Moved the folder over to my project folder, the `gulp build` command works.